# How do exploration maps work and where can I get them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft 1.11 just came out. With it, a new item was added: Exploration maps.
 The only thing I know about them so far is that they can be used to find a woodland mansion or an ocean temple, and can be bought from a villager. The minecraft wiki knows about the same, so I'd like to know:

- Can the map be obtained elsewhere than from a villager?
- What's the cost of the map?
- Mainly, how can the map be used to find a structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map basically works like any real life GPS. You see yourself and your target. Just move towards your target. It will help knowing where you look at, since the map is displayed with the North in the upper direction.

[image]

The costs may vary, but they should cost a large amount of Emeralds (15-30?) and one Compass. In survival, I'm certain they can only be obtained from cartographer villagers.

Answer (score 4):

An ocean explorer map can be bought from a cartographer villager for 12–20 emeralds and a compass, and a woodland explorer map can be bought from a cartographer for 16-28 emeralds and a compass, as their 4th trade. I guess that means that we have to find an unexplored village to find cartographers

Answer (score 2):

When you start moving and your dot ( character ) moves then you take out your map and keep moving, you should try to Direct to your dot to the  structure. When your dot arrives you look for the  structure and go to it.